# Credentials are already in use. The existing account in the session will be replaced

Tags: python, qiskit

I have written this code, and I want to run it on IBM hardware using API_TOKEN. My code is showing this error.

```
from qiskit import IBMQ 
# IBMQ.delete_account()
IBMQ.save_account('API_TOKEN', overwrite=True)
IBMQ.load_account()
```

Showing error in the line:**'IBMQ.load_account()'**

**a:** Credentials are already in use. The existing account in the session will be replaced.

**b:** Retrieve the hub/group/project sets available to the user.The first entry in the list will be the default set, as indicated by `hub`, `group`, and `project`, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in this codeappears to be correct, but there is an issue with the availability of IBM's services in Pakistan. IBM has discontinued its services in Pakistan, which means that local Jupyter notebooks can no longer access IBM Quantum Hardware. However, access is still possible through the cloud. Attached is the information related to IBM's open access plan for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`IBMQ.load_account` is for running instead of `IBMQ.save_account`. The first time, you save. From that point own, you can load it.

NOTE: consider that after `qiskit-ibmq-provider 0.20` (released in January 2023), the prefer package to connect with IBM quantum systems is `qiskit-ibm-provider`.